# Разблокировка блютуз замка

Tags: javascript, php, java, bluetooth, aes

Есть блютуз замок, пытаюсь разблокировать через приложение.
Сделал подключение, но не пойму, что надо отправить для разблокировки.
С документации только протокол.
Может кто то сталкивался с подобным
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nf4EePlZTvmeHm7nTFXAPW647zp2s6g7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Видимо, нужно сформировать byte[] (в соответствии с протоколом), где каждый байт имеет значение как в документации, и отправить его в канал подключения. А. Ну и, похоже, перед отправкой всё это надо зашифровать, а ответ расшифровать, как показано в примерах кода в документации.

Comment: @dimxenon можем как то обсудить?
Есть пара вопросов, не бесплатно можно